# Error '\"node .\bin\www\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file with gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gulp, nodemon

Hi I am using `gulp` and `nodemon` utility to automate my build process. It was working before I manually debug my application using vscode. I don't want to debug it now, want to run it simply.

I am running this command to start gulp and automate build if any changes in JS files but I am getting an error.

I checked some threads where it is suggested to use `set DEBUG=express:* & node bin/www` and it is working. I don't want to do this, don't know what it does. I wanna use `gulp`.

```
$ gulp
[18:11:31] Using gulpfile D:\api\gulpfile.js
[18:11:31] Starting 'default'...
[18:11:31] Finished 'default' after 101 ms
[18:11:31] [nodemon] 1.12.0
[18:11:31] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[18:11:31] [nodemon] watching: *.*
[18:11:31] [nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`
'\"node .\bin\www\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[18:11:31] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

gulpfile.js

```
const gulp = require("gulp"),
  nodemon = require("gulp-nodemon");

gulp.task("default", () => {
  nodemon({ ext: "js" });
});
```

www

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('cryptocurrency-api:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something is corrupted with nodemon version 1.12.0.
Had the same problem and solved it by removing and reinstalling an older version.

Remove nodemon using:
`yarn global remove nodemon`

And then reinstall - this time specifying an older version
`yarn global install nodemon@1.11.0`

Comment: try also removing nodemon locally
'yarn remove nodemon'
then verify that you have no more nodemon by trying to run nodemon. if it is not recognized then you can continue and reinstall

Comment: I am using gulp and gulp-nodemon

Comment: check gulp-nodemon github repo here https://github.com/JacksonGariety/gulp-nodemon
you can see in the package.json file that it has nodemon as a dependency.
but it is setup to install the latest nodemon. so it installed nodemon 1.12.0 for you. and that what breaks your code.

Comment: go to your node-modules. find gulp-nodemon and edit it package.json file so the nodemon version will be 1.11.0. then do what i suggested above in the answer

Comment: Thank you so much :) something is broken with latest version of nodemon